# Error on Google Colab on an installed package

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

In Google Colab, I am running below lines.

```
!pip3 install -U scipy
!git clone https://github.com/jnordberg/tortoise-tts.git
%cd tortoise-tts
!pip3 install transformers==4.19.0
!pip3 install -r requirements.txt
!python3 setup.py install

import torch
import torchaudio
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import IPython

from tortoise.api import TextToSpeech         # problem here
from tortoise.utils.audio import load_audio, load_voice, load_voices

tts = TextToSpeech()
```

This line has problem:

```
from tortoise.api import TextToSpeech
```

The error message says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0f6e1f002713> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 import IPython
8
----> 9 from tortoise.api import TextToSpeech
     10 from tortoise.utils.audio import load_audio, load_voice, load_voices
11

3 frames

/content/tortoise-tts/tortoise/models/xtransformers.py in <module>
      8 from collections import namedtuple
9
---> 10 from einops import rearrange, repeat, reduce
     11 from einops.layers.torch import Rearrange
12
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'einops'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried to "!pip3 install einops" and it says "Requirement already satisfied....". But the problem persists.

What went wrong and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the einops module is not being imported successfully even though you've installed it. This could be due to a version mismatch or an issue with the installation.

To troubleshoot and resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

Check Installed Packages: Verify that einops is installed in the same environment where you are running your code. You can do this by running:

**!pip3 list | grep einops**

If einops is listed, it means it's installed.

Version Compatibility: Ensure that the version of einops installed is compatible with the other dependencies in your project. Sometimes, certain versions of packages might have compatibility issues with other dependencies.

Reinstall einops: If the version is correct but you're still facing the issue, try reinstalling einops to ensure that the installation is not corrupted. Run:

**!pip3 uninstall -y einops**
**!pip3 install einops**

Restart the Runtime: Sometimes, in notebook environments like Google Colab, restarting the runtime can help resolve dependency issues. You can do this by clicking on "Runtime" -> "Restart runtime" in the Colab menu.

Update Dependencies: Ensure that all the dependencies required by tortoise-tts and its submodules are correctly installed and up-to-date.

After trying these steps, attempt to import TextToSpeech again and see if the issue persists. If it does, you may need to further investigate potential conflicts between dependencies or consult the documentation of tortoise-tts for any specific requirements or known issues.

Or try this if that doesn't work:

It seems like there might be an issue with the installation of the einops module, even though it appears to be installed correctly. Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

Check Installation Path: Verify that the einops module is installed in the correct location and accessible to your Python environment. You can do this by running:

**!pip3 show einops**

This command will display information about the einops package, including its installation path. Make sure this path corresponds to your Python environment.

Force Reinstall: Try forcing a reinstallation of the einops module to ensure that it is properly installed. You can do this by running:

**!pip3 install --force-reinstall einops**

This command will reinstall the einops module, potentially fixing any issues with the existing installation.

Upgrade Dependencies: Ensure that all dependencies required by the tortoise-tts library, including einops, are up-to-date. You can upgrade all packages to their latest versions by running:

**!pip3 install --upgrade -r requirements.txt**

This command will upgrade all packages listed in the requirements.txt file, which may include einops and other dependencies required by tortoise-tts.

Check Environment: Double-check that you are running your code in the correct Python environment where einops is installed. In Google Colab, make sure you're using the correct runtime environment with the appropriate packages installed.

Restart Kernel: Sometimes, restarting the Python kernel can resolve dependency issues. In Google Colab, you can restart the kernel by clicking on "Runtime" > "Restart runtime" in the menu.

After trying these steps, attempt to import TextToSpeech again and see if the issue persists. If the problem still occurs, there may be deeper compatibility issues or conflicts with other dependencies that need to be addressed.

Comment: thanks for the amazing help in details! the problem is resolved when the Runtime restarted after "!pip3 uninstall -y einops !pip3 install einops".

Comment: @Mark K: It was very likely generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar). It is easier to cut out the middlewomen and plagiarisers and go directly to ChatGPT (or similar). In any case, ChatGPT usually gets it wrong, but sometimes in subtle ways. It certainly isn't a source of truth, but more like interesting pointers.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, good point. it's from a blog post... https://medium.com/@gpj/making-your-ai-sound-like-you-a-guide-to-creating-custom-text-to-speech-8b595d5cf259